# Get unicode from FCKeditor in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, fckeditor

I am using FCKeditor in rails app. Input:

```
™ © ® ¢ € ¥ £ ¤
```

Present Output (ISO-8859-1 Entities):

```
&trade; &copy; &reg; &cent; &euro; &yen; &pound; &curren;
```

Expected output (Entity codes):

```
&#191; &#161; &#171; &#187; &#167; &#182; &#8224; &#8225; &#8226; &#8211; &#8212;
```

Please someone help me to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Configuration_Options/ProcessNumericEntities):

> **ProcessNumericEntities**
>
> This option tells the editor to transform all characters that are out of the ASCII table to their relative Unicode numeric entities.
>
> For example, if this option is set to true, the `Ϣ` sign will be transformed to `&#994;`. By default the option is set to false.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> FCKConfig.ProcessNumericEntities = true ;
> ```

So you just need to figure out where your FCKEditor configuration file is and add `FCKConfig.ProcessNumericEntities = true;` to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. I will try this and let you know :)

Comment: Hi This is not working as expected. It din't change any functionality. I have changed in FCKconfig.js file. Please let me know any other change has to do?

Comment: Is FCKEditor using that file?

Comment: yes.. It is the file in the public/javascripts/fckeditor/fckconfig.js